# Doxygen: Recognize all c++ comments

Tags: c++, comments, doxygen

I have a (finished) project for which i generate Doxygen docu.

The problem is, that the comments are standard c++ comments - no special doxygen comments. They look like this:

```
// This is a class.
class C
{
   // This is a method
   public: void f();   
};
```

So is there a way to configure DoxyGen to use all comments? If not, is there a tool around that can parse the code and transform the comments into DoxyGen-Comments?

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the comments by a regex. If you are using the `//` only for comments and not within string literals like `"Hallo//ABC"`, you can search and replace with the Pattern `/\/\/(.*)$/gm` by `/** $1 */`. See an example at https://regexr.com/3j7lc

Some Texteditor like Notepad++ support search and replace by Regex.

To search only for lines without some text before the `//` you can use `/^(\s*)\/\/(.*)$/gm`. Replacement pattern will look like `$1/** $2 */`

Comment: Basically a good idea to use regex. But i can not gurantee that nowhere in the code there is used a "//" for something different than commenting. Maybe only doing it for source files and only if the "//" is at the start of the line would be a safe strategy. You know the regex which only recognizes "//" at start of line?

Comment: The Caret (^) symbol signals nornally the start of the line in a regular expression.

Comment: @charly_b See my Edit